502 Bad Gateway Error from Nginx on Google GKE with PHP
I am requesting help with a current configuration issue in a Google Cloud Kubernetes environment (GKE) with PHP.
Our application is a PHP application using CodeIgniter.
It runs in Kubernetes Cluster with 2 nodes in Google Cloud, region us-central1 ( google/cloud-sdk:252.0.0)
The Database is a Google Cloud MySQL instance (mysql:5.7.25. )
There is a Nginx Load balancer somewhere in between.
We are getting a 502 Bad Gateway error, intermittently and can’t pinpoint where this is coming from. Getting accurate logging information with Google Cloud from PHP and/or Nginx is not straight forward. Many of the regular config files are not available in this setup.
From online research, it might be a configuration error of Nginx, or a communication issue between the PHP server and the database, or between the PHP API server and PHP UI.
Requesting help with configuration issues:  services.
“angular.js:14700 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"<html>\r\n<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n","status":502,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":https://stage.xyz.com/api/get_all_pre_eval_assessments/,"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"complete"}”
Any help would be appreciated.
